# Wiki Quote API "Batch Complete"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm working through freeCodeCamp's API challenges and the first one has me stumped, namely because I am a beginner.  I'm using wiki quotes and my end point is https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php.  My code is below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var API =  "https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php";

  $("#quoteBTN").on('click', function(){
  $.ajax( {
    url: API,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
      format: "json",
      action: "query",
    },
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
    });
} );
});
```

Which outputs to the console,

```
{batchcomplete: ""}
```

I believe I'm on the right track of getting the information I want, but I guess my question is, 
how do I select quotes?
how do I know where to go to know that to actually select?
On wikiquotes, I see they have 'selected pages', 'new pages,' 'quote of the day,' ... but do I attempt to access wikiquotes' DOM?

I'm using the follow codepen as a reference and attempting to learn how this person called the data, 'https://github.com/natetyler/wikiquotes-api/blob/master/wikiquote-api.js'

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, talking to myself here... but, I am on the right track and I am learning more about the wikipedia API and AJAX in general.

Keep it up Ryan, you're doing great

Comment: How Can you do this bro?